# npm install: fetchPackageMetaData error for material-design-icons@^3.0.1 unexpected end of file

Tags: node.js, npm, material-design, node-modules

I'm getting

```
fetchPackageMetaData error for material-design-icons@^3.0.1 unexpected end of file
```

while doing `npm install`. I've already tried cleaning cache (with force option) and deleting `node-modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file as well.

I suspect if it's related to Internet speed. Please suggest if I need to make any change to avoid the EOF?

Comment: try to install this package in private network. also try it after cleaning the `node_modules` in the `c:\user\appModule location `

Answer (score 1):

You experience this because of the many (many) svg files included in that repository - it jams `npm install` (issue [#133](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/133)).
Also, the [material-design-icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) project is on low maintenance and out of date for a while. There's a gap between the version in https://material.io/icons/ and the version in [material-design-icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons).

---

To resolve this issue (faced it myself), I've forked this repo and created [material-design-icons-iconfont](https://github.com/jossef/material-design-icons-iconfont)

- All irrelevant files has been removed (jams `npm install`)
- Maintaining updates for the icon-fonts straight from `Google Fonts` CDN (because [material-design-icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons)'s version is too old)
- Support for scss

Also, it comes with a light [demo page](https://jossef.github.io/material-design-icons-iconfont/) to assist searching and copy-pasting fonts

[image]